# How do I unset flags set in bazelrc?

Tags: bazel

My bazel.rc has flags that set up remote caching, but in certain situations I want to disable it, e.g. when running in an environment with network restrictions.

How do I "unset" the flags set in bazel.rc? For instance, bazel.rc sets `--google_credentials=/path/to/key`, so how do I override that and pass in null so it doesn't look for credentials?

I would like to retain the rest of my bazel.rc, so I don't want to simply ignore it.

Partial bazel.rc:

```
build --google_credentials=/path/to/key
build --google_default_credentials
build --google_auth_scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-source-tools
build --bes_backend=buildeventservice.googleapis.com
build --bes_best_effort=false
build --bes_timeout=10s
build --project_id=123456
build --remote_cache=remotebuildexecution.googleapis.com
build --remote_instance_name=projects/myproject
build --spawn_strategy=remote
build --genrule_strategy=remote
build --tls_enabled=1
build --remote_accept_cached=true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flags specified on the command line will override anything in the bazelrc file. So you can specify `--google_credentials=` to clear the value.

There are also other ways to set this up. In your case say you want `--foo=1 --bar=2` by default, but sometimes you want to turn those off. It would be annoying to have to remember all the flags to turn things off, so you can create configs. Your `bazelrc` file would look like this:

```
build --foo=1 --bar=2
build:nofoo --foo= --bar=
```

When do `bazel build` normally, you get `--foo=1` and `--bar=2`. When you don't want `foo` and `bar` you do `bazel build --config=nofoo`, which expands to `bazel build --foo=1 --bar=2 --foo= --bar=`, where the later flags will override the previous flags.

Comment: passing `--google_credentials=` doesn't clear the value (i.e. set it to `null`); rather, it sets the value to `''`, resulting in `Could not open auth credentials file ''`

Comment: Hmm, right. That would be a quirk of our flags parser. I'd file a bug about not being able to set --google_credentials to nothing. Also I got a NullPointerException when trying this, which is also a bug...

Comment: So there actually is a workaround, but it's kind of ugly. There's a feature called invocation policy that can control flags, but it's passed as a startup flag, so it can't be used with `--config`: `bazel --invocation_policy="flag_policies { flag_name: \"google_credentials\" use_default {}} flag_policies { flag_name: \"spawn_strategy\" use_default {}} flag_policies { flag_name: \"genrule_strategy\" use_default {}} flag_policies { flag_name: \"remote_cache\" use_default {}} flag_policies { flag_name: \"bes_backend\" use_default {}}" build <target>`.

Comment: You could put that in a shell variable if you wanted, and do `bazel $NO_REMOTE build <target>`. It's not super elegant, but it should work. You could also create an alias or shell function like `bazel_no_remote`. You could also move the flags for turning on remote caching into they're own config, but then you'd have to remember to use that config on each invocation.

Comment: Another alternative is to maintain two separate bazelrc files. One contains all the flags, minus the remote caching ones. Then your `~/.bazelrc` file imports the one with all the flags and adds the remote caching flags. That way by default you get remote caching, and to turn that off you specify the `--bazelrc` startup flag with `~/other_rc_file`. I notice however that you say "bazelrc", which is normally in your depot, so your flags would have to live in your bazelrc files in your home directory.

Comment: Great, glad that's working for you. One thing to keep in mind is that invocation policy overrides everything else, so whatever you set elsewhere on the command line or in bazelrc files will be overridden.

Comment: Just to clarify, only the flags that are specified in invocation policy will get overridden if they're specified elsewhere -- other flags will be unaffected.